# How to find with partial string from comma separated list of string then need to remove entire string from the list of values

Tags: mysql

We have requirement in Mysql query, to find with partial string from list of comma separated string. Then need to remove a found a string from comma separated list.

As per the below example, we need to find a string starting with "Pending" then need to remove found string from the comma separated list through Mysql query.

```
|-------------------|-----------------------------------------|
|         Id        |     Tag                                 |
|-------------------|-----------------------------------------|
|        1          |      Completed, #4CHD, Pending with ABC |
|-------------------|-----------------------------------------|
|        2          |      Open, Pending with Mrg, #4CHD      |
|-------------------|-----------------------------------------|    
|        3          |      Pending with cons, Resolved        |
|-------------------|-----------------------------------------|
```

**Output should be:**

```
|-------------------|-----------------------|
|         Id        |     Tag               |
|-------------------|-----------------------|
|        1          |      Completed, #4CHD |
|-------------------|-----------------------|
|        2          |      Open, #4CHD      |
|-------------------|-----------------------|
|        3          |      Resolved         |
|-------------------|-----------------------|
```

Answer (score 1):

For MySQL 8+

```sql
SELECT test.id, GROUP_CONCAT(TRIM(jsontable.value)) Tag
FROM test
CROSS JOIN JSON_TABLE(CONCAT('["', REPLACE(test.Tag, ',', '","'), '"]'),
                      '$[*]' COLUMNS( value VARCHAR(255) PATH '$')
                      ) jsontable
WHERE TRIM(jsontable.value) NOT LIKE CONCAT(@criteria, '%')
GROUP BY test.id
```

For MySQL 5.x

```sql
SELECT test.id, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(TRIM(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(test.Tag, ',', nums.num), ',', -1))) Tag
FROM test
JOIN (SELECT 1 num UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5) nums
    ON nums.num <= 1 + LENGTH(test.Tag) - LENGTH(REPLACE(test.Tag, ',', ''))
WHERE TRIM(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(test.Tag, ',', nums.num), ',', -1)) NOT LIKE CONCAT(@criteria, '%')
GROUP BY test.id
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=6ea901e1bab923cc4650c25dab32b46b)

---

> No rows should be ingnored in output. Let us assume 3rd row has Tag value as "Pending with cons" alone. I this case first two is getting displayed in output and 3rd row is ignored. My requirement is 3rd also should be displayed with empty Tag.

If so LEFT JOIN (and moving condition expression from WHERE to ON) needed:

```sql
SELECT test.id, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(TRIM(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(test.Tag, ',', nums.num), ',', -1))) Tag
FROM test
LEFT JOIN (SELECT 1 num UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5) nums
    ON nums.num <= 1 + LENGTH(test.Tag) - LENGTH(REPLACE(test.Tag, ',', ''))
    AND TRIM(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(test.Tag, ',', nums.num), ',', -1)) NOT LIKE CONCAT(@criteria, '%')
GROUP BY test.id
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e20fcbfc4c28fe0aa735bed6a58fc028)

Comment: @Mihai For 5.x version one need to parse the CSVs using static/synthetic numbers table and double `SUBSTRING_INDEX()`.

Comment: @Akina Here MySQL installed version is lower than 8.0. I'm facing following error: ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(CONCAT('["', REPLACE(tik.Tag, ',', '","'), '"]'),
                      '$[*]' ' at line 8

Comment: @Ramsethu *MySQL installed version is lower than 8.0* Add into the question precise server version. Also specify maximal separate values amount per `Tag` value.

Comment: @Ramsethu Updated. Adjust `nums` as needed.

Comment: @Akina This work fine. Thank you so much for your help. One minor issue i'm facing. No rows should be ingnored in output. Let us assume 3rd row has Tag value as "Pending with cons" alone. I this case first two is getting displayed in output and 3rd row is ignored. My requirement is 3rd also should be displayed with empty Tag. Please look at the url: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d71f58e11611a7eef20e703be9a4caef

Comment: @Ramsethu Added.